QGIS 3.34 How to avoid this coordinate overlap in the layout composer
I'm using PolyStrip and Atlas to generate some maps from a canal project, then using the angle of the plugin to orientation to the map in layout composer. But some grid coordinates just overlay depending from the angle and arrangement of grid. How can I avoid this? I just can't restricting X Y values because the map rotates and in some cases this results in maps without coordinates.


In Map Grid properties, Draw Coordinates section, you can set for Top/Bottom Show Longitude/X Only and for Left/Right Show Latitude/Y Only. It will eliminate coordinate overlaps. For map frames, you will find similar settings in Frame divisions.
